# CSV parser skips the empty cell by default

Tags: csv, groovy, opencsv

Here is my csv

```
0|A0|B0||D0
1|A1|B1|C1|D1
```

Here is the csvParser i am using

```
 file.eachLine() { line ->
                if (!line.startsWith("0")) {
                    def field = line.tokenize("|")
                    lineCount++
                    closure(lineCount,field)
                }
                else{   
                }
            }
```

So in the first line of CSV it doesnt have C), How can I say read that empty line too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this also does the trick:

```
file.splitEachLine( /\|/ ){ String[] parts ->
  if( '0' != parts[ 0 ] ){
    //do something with parts
  }else{}
}
```

God bless groovy! :)

Answer (score 2):

`tokenize` throws away empty tokens and returns a `List<String>`, try using `split` instead which returns a `String[]` and doesn't throw them away (see [here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2013/03/14/groovy-tokenize-vs-split/) for other differences)

Or use something like [GroovyCSV](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv/) and move the pain onto someone else's shoulders ;-)